# Initial velocities of a collision

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, collision, moment

This is the question:

A car of mass 900 kg and a van of mass 1300 kg collide at a crossroads. 
Investigation into the collision discloses that the car was travelling south east and 
that the van was travelling due north. After the collision, the damaged vehicles 
remained locked together and skidded off in a direction of 30 degrees north of east at an initial speed of 10 m.s-1 before eventually coming to rest.

Determine the speed of both vehicles before the collision.

Im struggling to work out the y components of the initial velocities ive got the x components.

Up to yet my workings out are;

[image: Physics]

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the car is traveling south-east, its south (-y) component of velocity and momentum will be the same as the respective east (x) components.

Don't forget south (-y) is opposite (negative) north (y).

Also, in the last line of the paper it seems 1500 should be 1300.